# plantUML class diagram not visualized and given error

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, uml, plantuml

I installed this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration) and tried to draw uml diagram using PlantUML in IntelJ (or Visual Studio code). But both IDEs gave the same error.

My code :

```
@startuml
Class01 <|-- Class02
Class03 *-- Class04
Class05 o-- Class06
Class07 .. Class08
Class09 -- Class10
@enduml
```

Ref : [code link](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram) 
this given error ,like this.

[image]

In my observation ,I feel `@startuml` is not recognized.  need some expert help to resolve this issue ?

I used following version.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `@startuml` is recognized but that you didn't install graphviz or that graphviz is not in your path

Comment: @albert yes, i only install plantUML. can u please give me ,instruction install it ?

Comment: @albert is it ok to install suing this link https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

Comment: I don't know how to install it in your case as I don't now what InteliJ will pick up. Basically install I would nstall graphviz and see to it that the graphviz bin directory is in my PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed  normally this graphviz  ,library using this link , [lib](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) ,and restart idea.Resolve the issue.

Comment: I was having this issue in Visual Studio code and the solution worked for that too.